# Do I need the Connection Bridge if I want to connect e-Health Sensor Shield with raspberry pi 3 model b?

Tags: connection, pi-models

I read [here](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/ehealth-sensor-shield-biometric-medical-arduino-raspberry-pi) in the description below that :

> This product is compatible with Arduino, Raspberry Pi (Model B+),
>   Raspberry Pi 2 (Model B) and Intel Galileo boards.

but this confused me for two reasons :
1- it written Raspberry Pi **2** (Model B), while it linked to Raspberry Pi **3** (Model B) 
2- if it is compatible to to Raspberry Pi **3** (Model B), then do I need to buy [the Connection Bridge](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/raspberry-pi-to-arduino-shield-connection-bridge) ?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it works with a Pi3.  It should.

You always need an adapter (e.g. connection shield) if your are using an Arduino shield (i.e. the linked product) with a Pi.

The Pi and Arduino are incompatible without an adapter.  They have different pin outs, pin functions, and an Arduino generally has 5V GPIO as opposed to the Pi's 3V3 GPIO.